# Redirect all pages & folders to home except one (/beta) using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I added this redirect string to .htaccess so all internal pages go to the staging site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

There is a problem with this: now I cannot access my /beta folder. How can I fix the string above to solve my issue?

Comment: `all pages & folders`. So why do you have a condition to avoid existing files ?

Comment: The old site is indexed in google and the new site isn't ready yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/beta
```

above RewriteRule.

Comment: This worked. I had to add this line to line 3 of the original string. thanks!